# Mongodb aggregation over multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, grafana

Because the large number of docs, someone decided to create everyday a new collection automatically in our Mongodb with the date as suffix with this format XXXXX_YYYY_MM_DD.

I want to use this DB as datasource in Grafana (with the JSON datasource). I have found aggregation queries that union several collections, but the problem is to dynamically get the dates to get the collections to union.

The only dates I can get from Grafana is __from and __to dates, so i can lookup the collections of these dates, but not the whole range of dates between from and to.

Any idea how to perform it?

Answer (score -1):

you can have some JS/shell script which can execute in mongo shell to get collection names:

```
var startDate= new Date("2021-09-01");
var endDate = new Date("2021-09-09");

var collections=[];
var startTime = startDate.getTime(), endTime = endDate.getTime();
//Then you could loop from one to another incrementing loopTime by 86400000 (1000*60*60*24) - number of milliseconds in one day:

for(let loopTime = startTime; loopTime <= endTime; loopTime += 86400000)
{
    var loopDay=new Date(loopTime)
    
    
 
    //generate collection for each day
    collections.push("COLLECTIONXXXX_"+loopDay.toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '_'))
}

print(JSON.stringify(collections))
```

Output:

```
["COLLECTIONXXXX_2021_09_01","COLLECTIONXXXX_2021_09_02","COLLECTIONXXXX_2021_09_03","COLLECTIONXXXX_2021_09_04","COLLECTIONXXXX_2021_09_05","COLLECTIONXXXX_2021_09_06","COLLECTIONXXXX_2021_09_07","COLLECTIONXXXX_2021_09_08","COLLECTIONXXXX_2021_09_09"]
```

In above example we had start date(2021_09_01) and end date (2021_09_09)and we have generated all collection names and stored in array, now you can use collection names from this collections array and run your aggregation union.

Comment: He asked about a solution in grafana